# NetworkManager disabled Wi-Fi connection

Tags: linux, networkmanager

I've experienced the following issue with NetworkManager.

All of a sudden, my wifi connection was lost and NetworkManager Applet (version 1.8.22) unchecked "Enable Wi-Fi" option. I had to manually check it and then connect to my home wifi network again.

I've identified related log entries:

```
Sep 24 18:20:45 pavel-pc NetworkManager[582]: <warn>  [1569342045.9154] sup-iface[0x556cb636c130,wlan0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Sep 24 18:20:45 pavel-pc NetworkManager[582]: <info>  [1569342045.9205] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now disabled by radio killswitch
Sep 24 18:20:45 pavel-pc NetworkManager[582]: <info>  [1569342045.9206] device (wlan0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 24 18:20:45 pavel-pc NetworkManager[582]: <info>  [1569342045.9208] dhcp4 (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 24 18:20:45 pavel-pc NetworkManager[582]: <info>  [1569342045.9208] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed bound -> done
Sep 24 18:20:45 pavel-pc NetworkManager[582]: <info>  [1569342045.9276] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 06:EA:00:C8:ED:A5 (scanning)
Sep 24 18:20:45 pavel-pc NetworkManager[582]: <info>  [1569342045.9286] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Sep 24 18:20:45 pavel-pc NetworkManager[582]: <info>  [1569342045.9369] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'supplicant-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

It doesn't seem to happen regularly, but I'd still like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

I think the tool that really disabled wifi was this rfkill (the second line in my log), but why?

The content of `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` is:

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

What should I look for in order to make sure this won't happen again?

Thank you